# Add a inline function with args in custom function directive

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vue-directives

This is how I could make a custom function directive in Vue.js:

```
<custom-element v-sample="doSomething" />

export default {
  ...
  methods: {
   doSomething() { 
    // do magic
   }
  }
}
```

The code of directive looks like this:

```
Vue.directive('sample', {
 bind: functrion(el, binding) {
  el.addEventHandler('anyevent', () => {
   return binding.value()
  })
 }
})
```

Now what I want to achieve is, passing function with arguments like this:

```
<custom-element v-sample="$emit('change', 'test', true)" />
```

Is there anything that I missed to read or to watch in the Vue documentation? Any intuitive way with real world example?

Comment: Directives allow you to simply pass javascript expressions, so I don't quite understand the question. Regardless, are you sure that a directive is the right choice here? I don't see how this emit should be triggered through a directive other than using a default event like click, which should rather be added by the @click directive on the element itself.

Comment: Ok then a directive is probably what you want. Have a look at my answer

Comment: Ofcourse Javascript expression, why didn't I know this before. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly, but this is probably some boilerplate of what you want:

```
Vue.directive('demo', function (el, binding) {
  // Add any event listener here that you want
  el.addEventListener('touchstart', () => {
    // Execute the function bound to the directive
    binding.value()
  })
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

And the template:

```
<div id="app">
  <h1 v-demo="() => {alert('hello')}">Click me for alert</h1>
</div>
```

Or in your case:

```
<custom-element v-demo="() => {this.$emit('change', 'test', true)}" />
```